# Example of extrema of two variables functions

Tags: calculus

Is there a class 2 function $f(x,y)$ with only two critical points, a relative minimum $a\in R^2$ and a relative maximum $b\in R^2$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$?

Comment: Example of such function: $$x^5-5x^3+10x +Mxy^2,$$ where $M>0$. Local maximum: $-4\sqrt{2}$ at $(x,y)=(-\sqrt{2},0)$. Local minimum: $4\sqrt{2}$ at $(x,y)=(\sqrt{2},0)$.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg567. This function has indeed two relative extrema, and the value at the minimum is larger than the value at the maximum. However, it has two additional critical points: $(\pm 1,0)$, which are saddles, but still critical points. This is the crucial part in the question: no more than two critical points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does the job:
$$
f(x,y)=x^5-5x^3+10x+x\Big(x^2-4+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\Big)^2.
$$ 
It comes from the example given by @Oleg567, but modifying the $y^2$ there to get rid of the extra critical points. This reduces to restricting the function to an open set diffeomorphic to the plane that excludes the saddle points. This is the quite general procedure of moving points around by a diffeotopy, and the key point for this particular example is in fact to have @Oleg567 function.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the graph of a function:

$$f(x,y) = -e^{-x^2 - y^2} + e^{-(x + 7)^2 - y^2} + x$$

then you will see that there exist such functions and they may look like that.

Comment: Thanks @Jakubussimus. It doesn't work but deserves discussion. Substitute $a$ for 7. Critical points come from
$$2xe^{−x^2}\!−2(x+a)e^{−(x+a)^2}+1=0,\ y=0$$
or
$$x=−a/2,\ y^2=\log(2a)−a^2/4.$$
Solutions of the 2nd system would have indefinite Hessian (small computation), hence saddles. Solutions of the 1st system are the critical points of the restriction of $f$ to $y=0$. As in one variable the example doesn't exist, there cannot be here exactly two critical points as wanted. And if each system has a unique solution, they coincide. For instance, for $a=7$ there is no critical point.